# Virtual machine ethernet failure on restore

Tags: virtual-machine, ethernet, udev

I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 on a Dell Inspiron 1545.
When I tried to resume a virtual machine, it showed "Error restoring domain:Cannot get interface MAC on 'eth0': No such device."
That's because after I rebooted, eth0 was changed to eth1.
First, I was bridging eth0 in virbr0.
How do I change eth1 back to eth0 interface?
Before that, when turned on the virtual network, I open the virtual machine, I can't connect to any websites until I shut down the virtual machine.

Comment: Your best bet is to reconfigure the virtual machine to use eth1, if you are using libvirt you can do this through the virt-manager gui. If you want to force the host OS to use a different name, check out this thread: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/512359-KVM-network-probs

Comment: Also relevant: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/512480-point-2-1-leap42-release-notes-Network-Interface-Names

Comment: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/512480-point-2-1-leap42-release-notes-Network-Interface-Names... that's a closed thread. Can't comment to it to see if it's helpful or not. Why can't threads just be open forever and ever so people can comment that it's helpless?

Comment: If it was almost any other distro I'd give you the full answer, I'm just not familiar with the network config utility open suse uses (wicked).

Comment: Now there is a duplicate of virbr0 without the ethernet bridged. I am afraid to connect back to the other one with ethernet bridged. Don't know whether that would change eth0 back to eth1, probably not?